# Connecting to NodeJS server from apache served page

Tags: node.js, apache

So basically I have a webpage runned by apache on port `1900` and I have a NodeJS server running on port `3000`. 
Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
//make sure you keep this order
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = 3000;
server.listen(port, '192.168.0.105', function(){
    console.log('Server started: listening on port '+port+'.');
});
```

On the webpage a have the following code:

`var socket = io('192.168.0.105:3000');` which connects to the NodeJS server when loading the page from the computer that runs the server(my laptop) and apache.
The problem appears when I try to access the webpage from another computer(laptop) connected to the same LAN that the laptop running the server is. 
When I access `192.168.0.105:1900` from that laptop, I only see the page that is being loaded from apache but doesn't connect to the NodeJS server, it tries to connect to `192.168.0.105:3000` forever but fails after 1 minute.

How do I resolve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: How do you make sure it is not connecting to the server? You're not even consoling anything on connecting to socket server.

Comment: First off, go to a command shell on the laptop and do a `ping 192.168.0.105` and see if you can reach that other server.  It could be a network issue or a local firewall issue.  Also, you should look in the debug console in the browser and see what errors are reported as that may provide further clues.

Comment: @Shaharyar in the console, it seems it tries to connect to `192.168.0.105:3000` but it loads forever, compared to my laptop which connects to  the sever in seconds.

Comment: Do you have a local firewall running on the computer that apache is running on that might not have port 3000 open when connecting from off the machine?  What OS is the computer with your server running on it?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's windows 7 SP 1, I am behind a router with port `1900` and `3000` forwarded

Comment: Windows 7 has a built-in personal firewall by default.  You may have to enable connections to port 3000 manually.  The router is presumably for access from outside the network.  Your are talking about accessing from your laptop when on the same LAN so that would more likely be the built-in personal firewall.

Comment: @jfriend00 any idea where I may find a guide on doing that ?

Comment: @jfriend00 it worked, I allowed it through windows 7 firewall and it worked, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it solved the problem.

Windows 7 has a built-in personal firewall by default. You may have to enable connections to port 3000 manually. The router is presumably for access from outside the network. You're talking about accessing from your laptop when on the same LAN so that would more likely be the built-in personal firewall.